# Google static map is not displaying

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am listing lots of businesses and their static google maps in my page (with a pagination). While going through the pages, sometimes Im getting the following image instead of maps. And if I refresh the page again, I will get the correct maps.

[image]

I am sure that I have **not reached the usage limit** (because Im getting the same maps on page refresh).

My sample request is given below . (Note: I am not passing any API key. Is it really required ? )

```
<img src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=168 Palmers Lane Pokolbin,POKOLBIN,NSW,2320,Australia&zoom=11&size=240x180&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)-ed urls to `src`:

```
<img src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=168%20Palmers%20Lane%20Pokolbin,POKOLBIN,NSW,2320,Australia&zoom=11&size=240x180&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false" />
```